# Return request in web method WCF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf

I have Web service and a method which makes a request to my table 'Customer' with Entity Framework.

I want to return the result of my request :

```
[WebMethod]
public Customer MyMethod(int id)
{
    Model model = new Model();
    Customer customer = new Customer();

    try
    {
        customer = model.Customer.Where(x => x.Name == id).First();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new System.NullReferenceException(ex.Message, ex.InnerException);
    }

    return customer;
}
```

My Class Customer (generated by EF) :

```
[Table("Customer")]
public partial class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? Adress_id { get; set; }

    public virtual Adress Adress { get; set; }
}
```

Class Adress (generated by EF) :

```
[Table("Adress")]
public partial class Adress
{
    public Adress()
    {
        Customer = new HashSet<Customer>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("Adress")]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Adress1 { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Town { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Customer> Customer{ get; set; }
}
```

But I have no answer when I call my method with SoapUI. If I delete the property virtual `Adress` then I have an answer but I need to get back the address also (joint)

Thank you

Comment: Guessing your model is the `dbcontext` change the line by `model.Customer.include("Adress ").Where(x => x.Name == id).First()`

Comment: It's identical, no answer by modifying the line

Comment: Can you explain what you need?

Comment: Return the result of my query. Customer + Adress

Comment: Are you sure you have an address related to that customer in your DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to load explicitly a relative property as part of the query, you can do that through Eagerly Loading, which is using `Include` extension method:

```
 customer = model.Customer.Include(c=>c.Address).Where(x => x.Name == id).First();
```

You can also use Explicit Loading:

```
 customer = model.Customer.Where(x => x.Name == id).First();
 context.Entry(customer).Reference(p => p.Address).Load();
```

Now I recommend you to check that relationship in your Database. If you are not using Fluent Api to to configure that relationship, then EF doesn't know that `Address_id` is the FK for that relationship. The foreign key property will be discovered by convention if it is named `[Target Type Key Name]`, `[Target Type Name] + [Target Type Key Name],` or `[Navigation Property Name] + [Target Type Key Name]`. One way to override this convention is using [`ForeignKey`](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx) attribute. So, first check the relationship in your DB and after that if you have an `Address` related to the `Customer` that you want to load. You should be able to load the `Address` navigation property using one of the two variants I propose above.

Comment: I have an error in `Include(c=>c.Address)` Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type. I have a relationship in my database : [relationship](http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/53/1451574932-foreign-key.png)

Comment: Include method is only for navigation properties.  You don't need to do that for scalar properties,  they will be loaded always when you load entity from your db

Comment: If I make a simple request I have well the automatic relation which is made : [img](http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/53/1451575383-cus.png) - [img](http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/53/1451575383-add.png)

Answer (score 0):

Because of the `virtual` properties it's impossible to serialize the models to send them. Your address in customer has references to customers, which has again references to address... That's an infinite loop. Because of this, you can use DTO (Data Transfer Object) classes to transmit the data. For your `Customer` model it would look like this:

```
public class CustomerDTO
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int? Adress_id { get; set; }

  public Adress Adress { get; set; }      
}
```

Before you send it over WCF you have to transform your `Customer` into `CustomerDTO` objects. You can even do that in one statement with linq:

```
var obectToTransfer = db.Customers.Where(c => c.Id == 5)
                                  .Select(c => new CustomerDTO
                                  {
                                     Id = c.Id
                                     ...
                                  }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: How to mapper both? thank's. Is it mandatory to go through this?

Comment: It depends, for example if you serialize to Json you can use [Newtonsoft json library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/), that has some options for serializing virtual properties. But overall it's good practice to use DTO's

Comment: if i write  `Adress = x.Adress` in the select, i have not a response

Comment: @Azertya Do you have the relation between customer and address mapped with fluent api?

Comment: I have a relationship in my database : [relationship](http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/53/1451574932-foreign-key.png)

Comment: But is the relationship defined in entity framework?

Comment: Yes , If I make a simple request I have well the automatic relation which is made [img](http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/53/1451575383-cus.png) - [img](http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/53/1451575383-add.png). I post a response : http://stackoverflow.com/a/34548732/5636732

Comment: @Azertya ah yes, I see, no idea why it's not loading the Address then

Answer (score 0):

I remove the Keyword virtual in my class customer :

```
[Table("Customer")]
public partial class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? Adress_id { get; set; }

    public Adress Adress { get; set; }
}
```

And I remove the constructor in my class Adress and the property `ICollection<Customer> Customer`

```
[Table("Adress")]
public partial class Adress
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("Adress")]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Adress1 { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Town { get; set; }
}
```

And my query : `customer = model.Customer.Include("Adress").Where(x => x.Id == 2).First();`

It works!

My response :

```
<a:Adress>
   <a:Adress1>101 Madison Ave</a:Adress1>
   <a:Id>1</a:Id>
   <a:Town>New York</a:Town>
</a:Adress>
<a:AdressId>1</a:AdressId>
<a:Name>John</a:Name>
<a:Id>2</a:Id>
```

But it's not practical

Comment: Why is it not practical? It's just xml

Comment: It is not practical to have to change my classes generated by EntityFramework to properly retrieve the result

Comment: In your original classes add `[ForeignKey("Adress")]` above `AddressId` in your `Customer` model. I think you just haven't got the relations mapped in entity framework, so lazy loading/eager loading is impossible

Comment: No, I haven't a response.Because of the virtual properties it's impossible to serialize the models to send them

Comment: Hence my answer about DTO classes, your solution now is very odd honestly :p

Comment: I would like to create a DTO class for Customer and Adress, and mapper both with the contents of my request